# Segmentation fault and code 139 while printing a string array

Tags: c

I get an `error 139` and a `segmentation fault` while trying to run, I'm a little baffled since I'm not accessing or creating any files or even getting input! I'm simply printing three arrays in order.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int i,x;
//set the values of the names
char nmbr[3][8]={
    "Andrés",
    "Manuel",
    "Peter"};
//print characters of the name 1 by 1
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    while(nmbr[i][x]!='\0'){
        printf("%c",nmbr[i][x]);
        x++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make the inner loop a `for` too

Comment: Why putchar in one case but printf("%c" in the other?

Comment: Mad Physicist, as you'll note this is a fairly beginner program, that is because I am a beginner, the book I'm using I'm using asks me to use different functions in the exercises that it has for me to get familiar with how they work and how to use them.

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't sure if it was on purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is not initialized which is UB

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    x = 0;
    while(nmbr[i][x]!='\0'){
        printf("%c",nmbr[i][x]);
        x++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Might as well use a `for` loop at that point

Comment: It worked, but why? I thought that the default value of "0" didn't had to be stated.

Comment: @IñakiUlibarri You have to initialize it before incrementing it, otherwise what are you incrementing? You will increment a garbage value and that's a cause for UB as the post states.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is uninitialized.  Your compiler should warn you about this.

You probably want `x=0` before the `while` loop.